# Extremely low p-value, even though null-hypothesis should NOT be rejected

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value

I'm doing hypothesis testing to check whether one variable affects another, by looking at the slope of the trendlines, on 268 datasets. From the analysis of each dataset (which contains many samples), I got a slope mean of -0.000948, and standard deviation of 0.002114. My null-hypothesis is that the slope is 0, i.e., there is no effect of one variable on the other. To check this I perform a two-sided student t-test, and I get t=-7.34 and p value = 2.57e(-12), which would mean I have to reject my null-hypothesis that there is no effect. I understand how I got that number, but that seems very wrong to me. If the slope mean is 0.000948, with also a low standard deviation, it should be clear that there is no effect.

I did the same thing with another similar dataset with mean -0.000364 and standard deviation 0.006219. This resulted with t=-0.96 and p=0.34. This seems more reasonable.

I have the feeling this is a matter of scale, but I don't know what to do to make this correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statistical significance is different from [clinical significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22clinical+significance%22). Your slopes are almost equal to zero, so the relationship is probably not "clinically" significant. But you presumably have a huge sample size, so the detected relationship is highly unlikely under the null hypothesis, so it is *statistically* significant.

With enough data, even tiny effects become (statistically) significant.

Comment: In particular, for the 268 cases in the first example the standard deviation of 0.002114 means a standard _error_ of 0.0001291, leading to the reported _t_ statistic.

Comment: Alright, I understand what's going on. So what should I do with a large sample, are there maybe some other tests which I could use?

Comment: Large samples are not a problem in themselves. It just makes more sense to pay more attention to "clinical significance". I personally am a big fan of "tapering effect sizes", i.e., everything influences everything else - but at some point, it becomes too trivial to care about. So I would recommend understanding your use case and figuring out what effect size is "relevant" - and probably discarding everything below that. Of course, you need a lot of domain knowledge for that.

Comment: @Sjotroll "are there maybe some other tests"
If you only have two variables, you can have a look at the correlation coefficient instead of the slope of the regression line.

Comment: @cdalitz True, but wouldn't that result in the same problem? There would also be 268 samples. However, if you only mean to say that I can look at the correlation coeff. instead of slope, but without hypothesis testing, then I agree, that would also be good and easier.